# What does a TypeScript index signature actually mean?

Tags: typescript, index-signature

I've been writing TypeScript for a while and am confused about what an index signature means.

For example, this code is legal:

```
function fn(obj: { [x: string]: number }) {
    let n: number = obj.something;
}
```

But this code, which does basically the same thing, isn't:

```
function fn(obj: { [x: string]: number }) {
    let p: { something: number } = obj;
}
```

Is this a bug? What's the intended meaning of this?

Answer (score 24):

You are right to be confused. Index signatures mean a few things, and they mean slightly different things depending where and how you ask.

First, index signatures imply that *all declared properties in the type must have a compatible type*.

```
interface NotLegal {
    // Error, 'string' isn't assignable to 'number'
    x: string;
    [key: string]: number;
}
```

This is a definitional aspect of index signatures -- that they describe an object with different property keys, but a consistent type across all those keys. This rule prevents an incorrect type from being observed when a property is accessed through an indirection:

```
function fn(obj: NotLegal) {
    // 'n' would have a 'string' value
    const n: number = obj[String.fromCharCode(120)];
}
```

Second, index signatures *allow writing to any index with a compatible type*.

```
interface NameMap {
    [name: string]: number;
}
function setAge(ageLookup: NameMap, name: string, age: number) {
    ageLookup[name] = age;
}
```

This is a key use case for index signatures: You have some set of keys and you want to store a value associated with the key.

Third, index signatures *imply the existence* of any property you *specifically* ask for:

```
interface NameMap {
    [name: string]: number;
}
function getMyAge(ageLookup: NameMap) {
    // Inferred return type is 'number'
    return ageLookup["RyanC"];
}
```

Because `x["p"]` and `x.p` have identical behavior in JavaScript, TypeScript treats them equivalently:

```
// Equivalent
function getMyAge(ageLookup: NameMap) {
    return ageLookup.RyanC;
}
```

This is consistent with how TypeScript views arrays, which is that array access is assumed to be in-bounds. It's also ergonomic for index signatures because, very commonly, you have a known set of keys available and don't need to do any additional checking:

```
interface NameMap {
    [name: string]: number;
}
function getAges(ageLookup: NameMap) {
    const ages = [];
    for (const k of Object.keys(ageLookup)) {
        ages.push(ageLookup[k]);
    }
    return ages;
}
```

However, index signatures *don't* imply that *any arbitrary, unspecific property* will be present when it comes to relating a type with an index signature to a type with declared properties:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
interface NameMap {
    [name: string]: number;
}
const m: NameMap = {};
// Not OK, which is good, because p.x is undefined
const p: Point = m;
```

This sort of assignment is very unlikely to be correct in practice!

This is a distinguishing feature between `{ [k: string]: any }` and `any` itself - you can read and write properties of any kind on an object with an index signature, but it can't be used in place of any type whatsoever like `any` can.

Each of these behaviors is individually very justifiable, but taken as a whole, some inconsistencies are observable.

For example, these two functions are identical in terms of their runtime behavior, but TypeScript only considers one of them to have been called incorrectly:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
interface NameMap {
    [name: string]: number;
}

function A(x: NameMap) {
    console.log(x.y);
}

function B(x: Point) {
    console.log(x.y);
}
const m: NameMap = { };
A(m); // OK
B(m); // Error
```

Overall, when you write an index signature on a type, you're saying:

- It's OK to read/write this object with an arbitrary key
- When I read a specific property from this object through arbitrary key, it's always present
- This object doesn't have *literally every* property name in existence for the purposes of type compatibility