# Why can I assign an empty object types {[key: string]: number}

Tags: typescript

this my code

```
interface clients{
    [key: string]: number
}
let x:clients = {}
```

I can’t understand why I can assign an empty object to x ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Just tried in my environment and I'm not seeing any linting errors.

Comment: Related: [What does a TypeScript index signature actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458308/what-does-a-typescript-index-signature-actually-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldnt it work?

with `[key: string]: number` you basically say *all property keys must be strings and the values must be numbers*. Because for JS objects *always* all property keys are strings it just says, that all property values of this object must be numbers. It does not make any statement about how many properties the object must have. This could be zero (as in your example) or arbitrary many.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, `{ [key: string]: number }` indicates that any index of that type results in a number. `{}` is closer to `Partial<{ [key: string]: number }>` (`{ [key: string]: number | undefined }`).

You might also consider using `Record<string, number>`.

`{ [key: string]: number | undefined }` is a safer type, anyways, especially with `strict` mode enabled. When you index a value whose type is that, the resulting variable is of type `number | undefined`. It forces you to validate that result in JavaScript.

```
const client = x['clientId'] // type = number | undefined

if (client != undefined) {
  // typeof client === 'number'
}
```