# How to explain this index signatrue: let value: Dictionary<number>['foo']?

Tags: typescript

I see the TypeScript handbook, in the Advanced Types section, it has code like this:

```js
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}
let keys: keyof Dictionary<number>; // string | number
let value: Dictionary<number>['foo']; // number
```

I can't understand the `['foo']`, if it just declare that the index is `string`?

hmm, i find that ['foo'] certainy not limit the var must be the value of key 'foo' of a dictionary, and the follow  statements is equivalent:

```js
let value: Dictionary<number>['foo'];
let value: Dictionary<number>['abc'];
let value: Dictionary<number>[string];
```

is it right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a TypeScript index signature actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458308/what-does-a-typescript-index-signature-actually-mean)

Comment: Have a look at that answer. Especially: "Third, index signatures imply the existence of any property you specifically ask for[.]"

Comment: `Dictionary<number>[string]` would probably not work but the rest are equivalent. `Dictionary<number>['a']` just means "the type of the property `a` of `Dictionary<number>`" and you know all types in the dictionary must be `T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected.

The generic `T` refers to the object values that are defined under the string key.

For better understanding let see at the object of type Dictionary:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

const obj: Dictionary<number> = {
 foo: 3, // ok
 abc: '' // wrong - value must be a number
}
```

If you get an `obj['foo']` you'll get a number 3, right?

The same refers for `Dictionary<number>['foo']` as you're requesting the type of Dictionary value under the 'foo' key so it will always return `T` (so `number` in our case).

As interface is an abstraction only you can pick whatever key you want so `Dictionary<number>['abc']` still return the same.

Comment: so, `let value: Dictionary<number>['foo']`  equals to `let value: Dictionary<number>['abc']`

Comment: Exactly, due to Dictionary expects a `string` value for a key. So if you give one, the output must be a number. Both `foo` and `abc` are strings so the result must be a `T` (number for your case )`

Comment: see my additional post pls

Comment: Yes, you're right. For further details please refer to the other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458308/what-does-a-typescript-index-signature-actually-mean

Answer (score 0):

You can access the types of an interface by accessing `['valueOfKey']` on the interface. For eg:

```
interface IMessage {
    id: string;
}

const value: IMessage['id'] = 1;
```

This will error out because `id` is declared as a string in `IMessage` and the value we are providing it is an number. Changing `1` to `"1"` would clear this error. Note that `IMessage` has only one property `id` and accessing any other property would result in an error on the accessor.

In the example you have provided, the interface is:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}
```

Accessing `foo` in `Dictionary` would give you the type when `key` is a string - which is `T`. The `T` passed is `number`:

```
let value: Dictionary<number>['foo'];
```