# Evaluate templated configuration in a loop

Tags: typescript

I have a system config (provided by me) that describes what a user config (provided by the user) is capable of.

Then I want to pass each piece of the user config and evaluate it according to the system setup.

To show what I mean, here is some sample code. It should output 2 lines:

- 123
- "whatever"

```
const systemConfig = {
  a: (arg: number) => arg,
  b: (arg: string) => arg,
}

type InferConfig<T extends {}> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (arg: infer U) => any ? U : never }

const userConfig: InferConfig<typeof systemConfig> = {
  a: 123,
  b: 'whateva',
};

// (everything above working as expected)

for (const key in userConfig) {
  if (key in systemConfig) {
    console.log(systemConfig[key](userConfig[key])); // correct output but highlights errors

    console.log(systemConfig[key as keyof typeof systemConfig](userConfig[key as keyof typeof userConfig])); // luckily doesn't work because I want to avoid "as" if possible
  }
}
```

**[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8QV0N)**

Another requirement is that the loop (not working section of the code) must not include logic in the form of "if (key === 'a') ..." (i.e. depend of `a`)

Answer (score 4):

You code does not contain the index signature for the type of Object: `systemConfig`. Which means any attempt of using `string` to index `systemConfig` will be prevented. For example we can define the Object with an index signature this way:

```
const systemConfig: {[key: string]: (arg: any) => string | number} = {
  a: (arg: number) => arg,
  b: (arg: string) => arg,
}
```

In the above code, `[key: string]` means `string` keys can be used to assign values to properties of `systemConfig`. And `(arg: any) => string | number` means the value should be a function that takes an argument of `any` type and returns either `string` or `number` (you can modify this)

Once done, you can remove this extra line of code and check it ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCe0CmBbAwuAZgSwOYC4YBvAbQGsl59oAnbMXAXUIAoBDGgmNseASgC8APhhgArigBGSGjAA%20cKHQYBfGAOIAoGN1Ycu4qTL7qR%20gDTaYkvZ0K16uE8O6dLKzZqjwADkhgAkmCYMhjBeAA8ACowSAAeUEhgACYQxCoiGkQwJADSMPQwFPAgmDBRzOV5jLEJSakw7HYFwTIwAKrOZrwwAPwdMIRgSABubR6aoJCwYhChWHiEQSE0YTi4Ed5%20pXCIiegLuJlaOmyEAIwATADMljo2MADkAO4AFmyJI2yP7gDcngB6AGNUYyeBQV6ObiSEBjGDPEA0MhQthpeJ%20YCJZJ8TyYRGNKbQIqUFowWbzcJOE4FMosYqkhDIA6UkxEKw6QkgAA2SAAdFyQLgWIz9ms8ORKIwWOTVocJfBGHw%20L8YECYKAaDQkJiYCAxFAfPrrEbIbhXly8K8oGjNYiIJ4dDogZyefzBcK9qgxbh5dw0sUdlskDsRV7DlKZd7fajiSUykGdpHw0qVWquWJgMiufAYMkQEgIGBHrAEUjrNq2OTAvCeLAoCBuCMQNhkjAAESots0mA%20EAQCDYSQ8qweDxAA)):

```
console.log(systemConfig[key as keyof typeof systemConfig](userConfig[key as keyof typeof userConfig]));
```

For your reference:
[What does a TypeScript index signature actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458308/what-does-a-typescript-index-signature-actually-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Usually we first define the config type and then extend the transformer.

But if you do want it, see below code.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAVATgQwQZyTiwFsIsoBeKAbwCgooBtAaShQSn2Cw7QF0AXFAAUOLGmF4QASioA+KNLoBfOnVCRYiVGgCSCMAFdgAHgxQIAD2AQEAE3zbk6bHkLEyWRdXqNW7JwA1hAgcEhQGEKRrPyWNnaOouKSgUjkUACqcpSK0lAA-FlQwggQAG7kquqa0PAuaADyJsZmFta2Dk71um4ERKTkPrQMzGwcUCFhEVHCGLHxnUliElIIsgppGZmFxaUVVWp0AMaI3Fwg3BAkPehUI4w4wiupCEYkAEbkOXkSADSjD7PFLCbi8BBoH5Kf7VDTgaAAZUuthIBla91u+kMJlMtXCFyuNx06HkcK0SMJzWA6OomKprVx8Px+GR10xpJOZ2AUCM+HImOEFJRaJM9z8SmEAEYAEwAZgBjCBUAA5AB3AAWOFs5RwyoBKgA3OokEYEMdgChEFAeO4BiRzItEt1iZhcP1PEMRDb3YMsHM-oFWsJMSK2vIZOKAPSRqBhIxQEi87n2ODW9UoJwAAxw+EzUC+xxwvOgtXwx14YG5CDg3I46QowHV0FOWCwEHNk1C1vho1OBG5Uyc1EaHwAVu3gAA6Qdet0eX1yHOiKb4jAyJj8I2MAYiPvnKZQfGDiOjRh7uAAGwgk4vcDQs9tHqwTCm-BEHFaL9C-BkMlGaiOb15xIEQWUJTEA2LLBMRkA0gA)

```
type ConfigTransformer = {
  [K in string]: (arg: any) => any
}

type ConfigInput<T extends ConfigTransformer> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (arg: infer U) => any ? U : never
}

type ConfigOutput<T extends ConfigTransformer> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (arg: any) => infer U ? U : never
}

const systemConfig = {
  a: (arg: number) => arg,
  b: (arg: string) => arg,
}

type SystemInput = ConfigInput<typeof systemConfig>
type SystemOutput = ConfigOutput<typeof systemConfig>

const userConfig: SystemInput = {
  a: 123,
  b: 'whateva',
};

function transform<T extends ConfigTransformer>(transformer: T, input: ConfigInput<T>){
  // you must do this `as` because typescript not infer the correct key type
  const keys = Object.keys(transformer) as (keyof T)[];
  for(const key of keys){
    console.log(transformer[key](input[key]))
  }
}

transform(systemConfig, userConfig);
```