Angular typescript >> Type vs Interface
I encountered an error
Type 'PaginationParams' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | number | boolean | readonly (string | number | boolean)[]; } | undefined'.
  Type 'PaginationParams' is not assignable to type '{ [param: string]: string | number | boolean | readonly (string | number | boolean)[]; }'.
    Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'PaginationParams'.ts(2322)
types.ts(11, 3): The expected type comes from property 'params' which is declared here on type 'Options'
(property) Options.params?: HttpParams | {
    [param: string]: string | number | boolean | readonly (string | number | boolean)[];
} | undefined

My product.service.ts (this class will call get() method from apiService)
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PaginationParams, Products } from '../../types';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductsService {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  getProducts = (
    url: string,
    params: PaginationParams
  ): Observable<Products> => {
    return this.apiService.get(url, {
      params : params, //this is where the error is at
      responseType: 'json',
    });
  };
}


My api.service.ts (this class will call get() method from httpClient)
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Options } from '../../types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  get<T>(url: string, options: Options): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, options) as Observable<T>;
  }
}


My types.ts file
export interface PaginationParams  {
  page: number;
  perPage: number;
};


export interface Options {
  headers?:
    | HttpHeaders
    | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
      };
  observe?: 'body';
  context?: HttpContext;
  params?:
    | HttpParams
    | {
        [param: string]:
          | string
          | number
          | boolean
          | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
      };
  reportProgress?: boolean;
  responseType?: 'json';
  withCredentials?: boolean;
  transferCache?:
    | {
        includeHeaders?: string[];
      }
    | boolean;
}


I am actually following a tutorial, and the guy uses interface for PaginationParams.
And for the error to go away, he added
export interface PaginationParams  {
    [param: string]:
          | string
          | number
          | boolean
          | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
  page: number;
  perPage: number;
};


Because to me it doesn't look type safe. it means that after page and perPage values provided, I could actually insert other values as well, like
this.productsService
      .getProducts('http://localhost:5021/api/product', { page: 0, perPage: 5, donkey: 20 })

So after troubleshooting and trying to figure why does the PaginationParams require the extra line of code to make the error go away. I ended up changing it to a type instead, and the error went off.
export type PaginationParams = {
  page: number;
  perPage: number;
};


The question is why?
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/angular-typescript-czk989?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fproducts.service.ts%3A20%2C5
Use Vs Code to see the error line
Because I am using a dotnet server at the backend, you won't be able to run the Angular server.

"i could actually insert other values as well" yes. Spicy hot take: an API (whether over the wire or not) should always be prepared to get more than it asked for. "I ended up changing it to a type instead, and the error went off" it shouldn't: Typescript does not let an object literal specify unknown properties that aren't part of it's type.

If you could [edit] your code to be a small [mre] we can paste into a standalone IDE and immediately reproduce, then it'll be easier to answer. I think you might be asking this question but without an easy-to-verify [mre] I can't be sure. Is that the same issue or am I missing something?

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/angular-typescript-czk989?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fproducts.service.ts%3A20%2C5
You need to use VS Code to see the squiggly error line

That's not a [mre] if I need to navigate away from SO to see the code. Ideally you'd pare it down to something not requiring anything more than just an interface and a type that display the difference you're talking about. I'm closing this as a dupe of this question and if that's not right then feel free to vote to reopen after [edit]ing to provide evidence of the non-duplicativeness (that's not a word, sorry). Good luck!

Thank jcalz! Sorry for the trouble.
I got the answer now
"Just to fill people in, this behavior is currently by design. Because interfaces can be augmented by additional declarations but type aliases can't, it's "safer" (heavy quotes on that one) to infer an implicit index signature for type aliases than for interfaces."

RyanCavanaugh
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300


The issue arise because of how index signature is defined
"An index signature is a way to define the Shape of fields which are not known ahead of time."
"[it]...describes an exact set of fields to match on an object."
And since interfaces are augment-able (by having interfaces with the same name but different field properties), hence due to that nature of interfaces it will be hard to ascertain how the field will turn out.
More on this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458308/what-does-a-typescript-index-signature-actually-mean
